# replace zero with text using sed or awk

Tags: sed, awk

I have text file which looks like as shown below:

```
 0  chr23:54039     0   54039
 0  chr23:103278    0   103278
 0  chr22:174609    0   174609
 0  chr22:54039     0   54039
 0  chr25:103278    0   103278
 0  chr25:174609    0   174609
 26 chr26:174609    0   174609
```

If the first column is '0' i need to replace the 0 in the first column with the number after chr. So, the output should look like:

```
23  chr23:54039     0   54039
23  chr23:103278    0   103278
22  chr22:174609    0   174609
22  chr22:54039     0   54039
25  chr25:103278    0   103278
25  chr25:174609    0   174609
26  chr26:174609    0   174609
```

Can anyone provide a simple sed or awk any linux solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With sed:

```
$ sed -r '/^0/s/0(\s*chr)([^:]*)/\2\1\2/g' file
23  chr23:54039     0   54039
23  chr23:103278    0   103278
22  chr22:174609    0   174609
22  chr22:54039     0   54039
25  chr25:103278    0   103278
25  chr25:174609    0   174609
26 chr26:174609    0   174609
```

Without `-r`:

```
$ sed '/^0/s/0\(\s*chr\)\([^:]*\)/\2\1\2/g' file
23  chr23:54039     0   54039
23  chr23:103278    0   103278
22  chr22:174609    0   174609
22  chr22:54039     0   54039
25  chr25:103278    0   103278
25  chr25:174609    0   174609
26 chr26:174609    0   174609
```

The idea is to replace lines starting with `0`. In those, the `0...chrNUM:...` is caught and printed back with desired format.

With `awk`:

```
$ awk '/^0/ {split($2,a,":"); gsub("chr", "", a[1]); $1=a[1]}1' file
23 chr23:54039 0 54039
23 chr23:103278 0 103278
22 chr22:174609 0 174609
22 chr22:54039 0 54039
25 chr25:103278 0 103278
25 chr25:174609 0 174609
26 chr26:174609    0   174609
```

Given lines starting with `0`, the 2nd field is broken into pieces by `:` delimiter and then `chr` text is removes. Then it is ready to be stored as first field. `1` makes the condition true, so the full new line is printed.

Comment: @realspirituals check all versions

Comment: So weird, that I dont get answer for all three of them. I might be doing something wrong for sure. But i tried it in ideone.com and also on my linux box. Nothing works!!

Comment: @realspirituals note that the OP input has a space before each line. I removed it in my tests because I guess it is an error.

Comment: After removing the leading WS, All three works fine. Thanks mate.

Comment: @fedorqui couldn't split and gsub have been combined in either one of them in `awk`?

Comment: @jkshah yes, completely. I realized when seeing Jotne's good answer.

Comment: @fedorqui: +1 for completeness and the comments (in the answer, and in your comments below it too).

Comment: @fedorqui: ... however the condition should be `/^0 /` instead of `/^0/`. Or it could be `($1 == 0)`

Comment: @OlivierDulac thanks. Note that adding a space `/^0 /` is not the final solution, as it may have a tab instead of a space. `/^0/FS` would be better, and in the `BEGIN{}` group the field delimiter would be set.

Comment: @fedorqui: or simply: `($1 == "0")` ?

Answer (score 6):

If number in column #1 is always the same as `chr` number you can do this with `awk`

```
awk '{split($2,a,":|chr");$1=a[2]}1' file
23 chr23:54039 0 54039
23 chr23:103278 0 103278
22 chr22:174609 0 174609
22 chr22:54039 0 54039
25 chr25:103278 0 103278
25 chr25:174609 0 174609
26 chr26:174609 0 174609
```

Comment: @Jotne: +1 for elegance and insight on awk usage. The more I learn awk, the more I love it (the ability to have several separators, or here to have `split` on either `:` or `"chr"`, is marvelously efficient and powerful.)

Comment: @Oliver: Thank you for the head up :).  `awk` is very powerful, and when you think you have seen the most, a new usage of it surface.

Comment: note that this one recreate the whole 1st column, ie, it doesn't change only line with "0" in the first column like the OP asked. [it *seems* to be the same thing, given the small example, as it *seems* the OP's file have already some value taken from the 2nd field... but it could be just coincidence of the example?]. Adding the condition would be a simple tweak: just add `/^0 / ` before the `{` so that that change (split, etc) only occurs on line starting with "0 ".

Comment: Its stated i my post.This can be solved by starting awk with `!$1` like this `awk '!$1 {split($2,a,":|chr");$1=a[2]}1'`

Answer (score 0):

```
sed "s/^0[[:blank:]]\{1,\}chr\([0-9]\{1,\}\):/\1 chr\1:/"
```